# Android 5.0 sync questions on HTC M8

Tags: sync, 5.0-lollipop

I'm trying to figure out how to set items to individually auto sync.

On the HTC M8 under accounts & sync in both 4.4 and 5.0, I noticed I cannot select items to auto-sync individually. I can only manually sync individual items when I have auto-sync turned off. If I turn on auto-sync, it automatically wants to sync everything under those accounts and Google account which is what I do not want.

I only want certain things under these specific accounts to auto-sync. For instance, all I use is Gmail and Google Play Music. I do not want anything else on my phone to sync to Google, but I can't figure this out since it doesn't ask what I want synced before adding an account.

I know in older versions of android, it always asked what I wanted to have auto-synced and what I didn't when adding the account. I could also go in that account under settings and select what I wanted to auto-sync before turning on the phones sync.

How can I get around everything trying to sync at first, if I cannot even choose what I want to sync when adding a Google account?

I've even tried sighing into these separately instead of adding the main Google account through accounts & sync. It still does the exact same thing and it adds everything from my Google account ready to be synced as soon as I turn on the phones auto-sync.

Comment: If you go to accounts & synch, and click on your google account it should have the breakdown (I tried it on an M8 just now, fine) Chrome, Music, Gmail etc etc etc. What happens if you clcik on the Google Account itself (and not the little synch icon beside it)?

Answer (score 0):

Enable "Sync" in the taskbar, then go to the account you need selective sync on, you'll find all the required options with tickboxes. Tickboxes disappears when "Sync" option is disabled.

Best luck.